# how to include NTL using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, gmp, ntl

I use this line to compile a simple program:

```
g++ main.cc -lntl -lm -lgmp
```

How do you include this into CMake?

```
find_package(NTL REQUIRED)
find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
```

Doesn't work. And gives the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
  Could not find module FindNTL.cmake or a configuration file for package
  NTL.
...
.
```

and

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -lntl -lm -lgmp)
```

Doesn't work either (but I think it's just wrong in general).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If `ntl`, `m`, and `gmp` libraries are usually installed to somewhere in the default path (e.g. `/usr/` or `/usr/local/`), you could simply do something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
add_executable(test main.cc)
target_link_libraries(test ntl m gmp)
```

This is probably closest to your original g++ command, but it isn't very robust however; if any of the libraries aren't found, you won't know about it until you try linking.  If you want to fail at configure time (i.e. while running CMake), you could add `find_library` calls for each of the required libs, e.g.

```
find_library(NTL_LIB ntl)
if(NOT NTL_LIB)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "ntl library not found.  Rerun cmake with -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"<path to lib1>;<path to lib2>\"")
endif()
```

You'd then have to change your `target_link_libraries` command to

```
target_link_libraries(test ${NTL_LIB} ${M_LIB} ${GMP_LIB})
```

You'd probably also then have to do a `find_file` for one of each lib's header files to find out the appropriate path to add via the `include_directories` command (which translates to `-I` for g++).

Note, it's important to put quotes around the extra CXX_FLAGS arguments, or CMake treats them like separate values in a list and inserts a semi-colon between the flags.

For further information about `find_library`, `find_file`, etc. run:

```
cmake --help-command find_library
cmake --help-command find_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your error:

It doesn't look like there's a `FindNTL.cmake` module included with CMake. That means you'll have to either:

- Write your own `FindNTL.cmake`,
- Find another that somebody else has written,
- Hack together a solution that:

  - Checks if NTL is installed
  - Provides link targets, relevant flags, etc.

From a (rather quick) Google search, it appears somebody has [an NTL module for CMake](https://github.com/vernamlab/cuHE/blob/master/cuhe/cmake/FindNTL.cmake). Since NTL use GMP, you will probably need [the associated GMP module for CMake](https://github.com/vernamlab/cuHE/blob/master/cuhe/cmake/FindGMP.cmake). It doesn't look like a fully-featured CMake module, but it also appears to be the best thing out there (again, it was a *quick* Google search, and I don't use NTL).

To use, you'll want to add some things to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Let CMake know where you've put the FindNTL.cmake module. 
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/CMake/Modules")
# Call the FindNTL module:
find_package(NTL REQUIRED)
```

---

> SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -lntl -lm -lgmp)

Yes, this is wrong. You don't want to be setting your `CXX_FLAGS` with *linking* directives. I would use:

```
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=cxx0x )
```

to set the Cxx standard you want to use. To actually link to libraries, you'll want to:

- Ensure that you've found the libraries (with the relevant `find_package ( FOO )` lines)
- Link those against your target, like this:

  ```
  # Build the Foo executable. (Or library, or whatever)
  add_executable (FooEXE ${Foo_SOURCES} )
  target_link_libraries (FooEXE
      ${bar_LIBRARIES}
      ${baz_LIBRARY}
      )
  ```

  Please note! `${bar_LIBRARIES}` and `${baz_LIBRARY}` is not a typo; there's no standard way of setting the relevant libraries in the `FindFOO.cmake` modules, which is, in my opinion, an annoyance. If one doesn't work, try the other, or, worst case, have a look in the relevant `FindFOO.cmake` file (there's a bunch installed with CMake by default) to see what each one uses. With the link i provided, you can use ${NTL_LIB} and ${GMP_LIB}.